# How to avoid Pool from executing multiple times actions that I don't want it to execute

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

my problem is that I want to use a Pool to execute a function over several links so I get the result faster. I use webdriver to get those links. Once I have them, I close the driver and I tell the Pool to do what I said before. It is then when multiple windows are opened by the driver. This is the code. (The function isn't relevant I think)

```
 deporteElegido = 'Fútbol'

web = 'https://sports.williamhill.es/betting/es-es'
PATH = 'C:\WebDrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

inicio = time.time()

driver.get('https://www.betfair.es/sport/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()
except:
    pass
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui-expandable allSportsLink allSportsMainLink ui-betslip-action"]').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
enlaces = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="full-sports-item"]')
deportes = [enlace.text for enlace in enlaces]
indice = deportes.index(deporteElegido)
enlaces[indice].click()

time.sleep(2)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="avb-col avb-col-runners"]//a')
enlaces = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]
driver.quit()

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    print([x for x in executor.map(extraccionFutbolBetfair, enlaces)])
fin = time.time()
print(fin-inicio)
```

Comment: To avoid windows opening (which is what I assume is your problem), you should set the headless option when constructing the driver. Also, consider whether you really need to use selenium for those discovered hrefs. You might just need *requests* or *urllib*

Comment: What do you mean with: "you should set the headless option when constructing the driver"? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: For `headless` mode you can learn from these links - [Link1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/driving-headless-browser-testing-with-selenium-and-python) , [Link2](https://duo.com/decipher/driving-headless-chrome-with-python)